# Delete item from a ListView if file exist

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

i created a list view inside MapsListActivity that display items from an array located in string.xml.

This list view allow to view maps or download relative  maps  if is not present.

In Switch, case 0 send the user to another activity called MyMapsActivity.

MyMapsActivity extends MapsActivity.

MyMapsActivity should display the same list view but with the exception to just show the list of the maps already downloaded in the device.

My idea was to use an if else to check if the map is present in the device, so if the map is present, don't show list of maps that are not present in the device.

How can i solve this problem? Everything i tried so far, it was unuseful.

MapsListActivity.Java

```
public class MapsListActivity extends AlertDownload implements OnItemClickListener{


private static final File PRATO5_MAP = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/", "pratonew5.map");
private static final File PRATO4_MAP = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/", "pratonew4.map");
private static final File PRATO3_MAP = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/", "pratonew3.map");
private static final File PRATO2_MAP = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/", "pratonew2.map");
private static final File PRATO1_MAP = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/", "pratonew1.map");





ListView listView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String osmdroidFolder = "/osmdroid/";
      String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      File myOsmdroidFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + osmdroidFolder);
      myOsmdroidFolder.mkdir();

  String tilesFolder = "/osmdroid/tiles/";
      File myTilesFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + tilesFolder);
      myTilesFolder.mkdir();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mapsList);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position){
    case 0:{
        Intent Info = new Intent(MapsListActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(Info);
    }
    break;
    case 1:{

        if (PRATO1_MAP.exists()) {
            Intent Info = new Intent(MapsListActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(Info);
        }
        else{
            DialogDownload1();
        }   
    }
    break;
    case 2:{

        if (PRATO2_MAP.exists()) {
            Intent Info = new Intent(MapsListActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(Info);
        }
        else{
            DialogDownload2();
        }   
    }
    break;
    case 3:{

        if (PRATO3_MAP.exists()) {
            Intent Info = new Intent(MapsListActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(Info);
        }
        else{
            DialogDownload3();
        }   
    }
    break;
    case 4:{

        if (PRATO4_MAP.exists()) {
            Intent Info = new Intent(MapsListActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(Info);
        }
        else{
            DialogDownload4();
        }   
    }
    break;
    case 5:{

        if (PRATO5_MAP.exists()) {
            Intent Info = new Intent(MapsListActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(Info);
        }
        else{
            DialogDownload5();
        }   
    }
    break;
    }

}

    }
```

MyMapsActivity.java

```
    public class MyMapsActivity extends MapsListActivity {



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
          android:layout_width='fill_parent'
          android:layout_height='fill_parent'
          android:orientation='vertical' >

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mapsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:entries="@array/maps_array"
           />
       </LinearLayout>
```

string.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

        <string name="app_name">Maps</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

        <string-array name="maps_array">
            <item>MyMaps</item>
            <item>Prato1</item>
            <item>Prato2</item>
            <item>Prato3</item>
            <item>Prato4</item>
            <item>Prato5</item>
        </string-array>

    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you look for all mapfiles in your "/osmdroid/tiles/" directory and then add these dynamicly to the ListView in your MyMapsActivity. You could use the listFiles() Method of Javas File class.

```
File f = new File(extStorageDirectory + tilesFolder);        
File file[] = f.listFiles();

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_row_item, file);  
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

something like that, if the map isn't in your tilesfolder it won't be displayed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. i am really new in android, so i don't really understand clear. Could you give me an example please?

Comment: This tutorial could help you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample

Comment: So, for what i see, you think is better not to extends MapsListActivity but create a new list view?

Comment: yes because if you extend your MyMapsActivity and you have less than 5 maps in your list, you will get probably false results in your onItemClick method. try to find some tutorials about custom list adapters these will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately if i create a new list view, i will loose all the implements i made in MapsListActivity.

Comment: You still can extend from your previous activity, just change the way how the data is handled. dont use an array from the strings.xml define the default array in your activitiycode and send it to your listadapter. in your MyyMapsActivity do the same just with the array which contains the downloaded maps. you have to remove the android:entries in your activity_main.xml

Comment: The problem is that i use the strings.xml because i need to write different dictionary for different languages.